# Import just Facebook friends

Tags: java, android, facebook

I started to programming in Android a few weeks ago. And I have some Java skills.

So I am creating an app which needs to get the Facebook friends list (just the names not the pictures). I Googled and most people said "read the Facebook api".
How can I get the list of friends?

Answer (score 1):

The friends.get command gives you all friends from a corresponding user. You find the description of the REST webservice command here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.get/

If you program in Java you need the facebook java api
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

Here's a short example how to connect to facebook api and how to get a user's friends list and further operations
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

To implement the Facebook Graph API in an Android app, use the Facebook Android SDK - you can find it on [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). It includes an example app called [Hackbook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook). You can read about Hackbook's features [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook). By going through the Hackbook's code you can learn how to do user authorization and login to Facebook on Android.

The Hackbook contains sample code for how to get a list of friends - see [source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/FriendsList.java) and details on [Facebook Developer pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/#friends).